# macbook pro encounters prohibited sign while booting with USB

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, usb, startup

My macbookpro is completely empty and the only option that I have is just internet recovery. I downloaded el capitan and with help of the terminal in the internet recovery build a bootable OSX el capitan. So when I hit <kbd>c</kbd> in startup, apple logo appears. Meanwhile progress bar goes half way and **suddenly apple logo changes to prohibited sign**. I also made a mavericks bootable usb. same results.

Comment: Boot in verbose mode... What is the last few lines. It might be  "Still waiting for root device"

Comment: @RACING121  Yes That is exactly "still waiting for root device". So what should I do

Comment: Try moving the USB to another port. If no success try creating the bootable media again. This usually happens when OSX doesn't detect your USB fully. Able to boot from but cant properly mount

Comment: @RACING121 Thank you. I'll try that. should I by another usb device?

Comment: if all fails you can try another usb

Comment: @RACING121 I bought an 8 gig Sony USB memory. It worked with my new USB device. :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In verbose mode, you will find that OSX gets stuck at:

> Still waiting for root device

This error usually happens when your media used to boot OSX is not detected properly and can't be mounted. You can therefore try these methods to get it to work:

- Changing the port you insert your USB into
- Remaking the bootable media
- **Getting a new USB**

If all fails your device may need special drivers of some sort. You can also check it out with an *Apple Genius.*